# Determining if a metadata property is indexed or not

Tags: search, 2013, managed-metadata, managed-property

This question is related to my previous question which not been answered. When I go to Search Schema I can find the corresponding managed property for the Managed Metadata Site Column, and it is bound to a Crawled property (`owstaxIdMySiteColumn` is the Managed Property).

It is marked as selectable, queryable, searchable and refiner everything. Does it mean that it is indexed? If it is indexed why I cannot filter my search based on it?

I mean if I search based on the `contentTypeId` it returns all Items in the list, but when I filter based on the managed property it returns nothing. and I send `selectproperties=owstaxIdMySiteColumn` but it does not returns the column at all, even with `selectproperties=MySiteColumn` the column not be returned.

Comment: Has a Full Index occurred since you added the Managed Property?

Answer (score 0):

Did you added site column as a Taxonomy field yet if not then follow this blogpost,

> Creating a site column that holds a value from managed meta data term
>   store is not directly available.
>
> We first need to create a site field which is of type taxonomy and
>   then we need to create one feature which is scoped at site level and
>   in feature activation we access the taxonomy store and set the site
>   column to required term set.

[Managed Metadata Site Column in SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2013/03/create-managed-metadata-site-column-in.html)

Can you also confirm if you went through all of *relevant* steps in this post,

[Enable advanced search for custom columns SharePoint 2010](http://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/add-custom-search-properties-in-your-advanced-search-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: thanks, Yes I have created Site Column of type taxonomy by using GUI no code I have used.